# How to go about debugging non-responding Grails application?

Tags: windows, debugging, grails

I'm partaking in the development of a Grails application. It was working alright, but when I started it up this morning, the following happens: When calling up a certain page, the server ceases working. It does not respond, there's nothing in the log4j logs and following that all other pages too are not reachable. Further (as far as I know) we're using the [kickstart plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/kickstart-with-bootstrap) - that names keeps appearing in the logs (as if there's a cron running a script every few moments) but no longer after said page call.

I've checked the most recent edits against the code base used (containing last version considered stable) and there were no significant changes (that'd explain what happens) since the last checkout.

I'm at a loss as to what to do now. I checked online for hints but found none. How should I go about debugging this error? Where should I start? Where should I look for what information?

As this is an in-development branch of the application, it currently sits on my localhost (running grails on a windows machine) and I'm able to perform any kinds of operations on it. As IDE I've Eclipse with grails plugin, so I can debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually no simple solution. First, you need to find out why the Java VM hangs. Follow the instructions in this document: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/hangloop-140257.html

When you found out the reason why it hangs, come back here if you need ideas how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Aaron Digulla - following chapter 5.1 I found the pid (on windows) with `netstat -a -n -o | find "8080"` and then used that to retrieve a stack thread with `jstack -F <PID>` - BEFORE accessing the page mentioned, jstack gave me a result with "No deadlocks found." and plenty of threads, all of which in "state = BLOCKED" or "state = IN_NATIVE". AFTER accessing the page jstack gave the error message "Error attaching to process: Windbg Error: WaitForEvent failed!" and netstat found no process was listening anymore on port 8080. No idea where it went.

Comment: @HumanInDisguise: That means the process died. Try to run it from a console window to see it's output and/or look into any log files which the process/application creates and look for errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Aaron Digulla I ended up installing an using [Windows Debug Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but attaching that to the process to see what it did when it crashed actually kept it indefinitely from crashing (while not delivering any output); the moment I stopped the debugger the process crashed. Eventually, the issue stopped to appear when we restructured the application. The page shows plenty of data. We now only let it display a few rows of data and let the remainder load delayed via javascript.